# QTreeView: Drag-And-Drop fails to call QAbstractItemModel::dropMineData (source code in the post)

Tags: drag-and-drop, qt4, qtreeview, qtreewidget, qabstractitemmodel

I am building an app with a treeview and I created a model which derives from QAbstractItemModel. I can manipulate the tree by dropping a file (dragging the file from outside of the app into the app) and drag-and-drop items within the tree.

The problem is that the file drop into the app doesn't **always** work since I re-implemented the function `mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes)`. **Sometimes** and only when there is a selected item in the tree (which provides a valid item index to the function `mimeData`), the file drop doesn't work because the function `mimeData` is called but the function `dropMimeData` is never called.

I had to re-implement the function `mimeData` to be able to create my own mimeData which is used during drag-and-drop within the tree. This mimeData is used in the function `dropMimeData`, which works fine.

It looks like that the function `mimeData` should not be called during the file drop as the application knows already the mimeData format: `text/uri-list`.

My function `dropMimeData` processes both my own mimeData format and `text/uri-list` format.

Does anybody have the same issue or have any thoughts on this?
Again it is not like if it was not working at all, it only fails some of the time.

Any help or thoughts would be great.

Cheers.

The following might be totally unrelated, it is something I came across while trying to debug this. It looks like that there might be relation with the state of the window: `QEvent::WindowActivate` or `QEvent::WindowDeactivate`. During the file drop, the window becomes inactive and active again but the problem seems to occur when the window fails to become active again. ?

I added the source code to reproduce the problem. Drop a file into the app. Select the item in the tree. Drop more files. Sometime the drop doesn't work???

```
// main.cpp
#include "dragdropmainwindow.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    DragDropMainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

 // dragdropmainwindow.h

  #ifndef DRAGDROPMAINWINDOW_H
  #define DRAGDROPMAINWINDOW_H

  #include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
  #include "ui_dragdropmainwindow.h"

  #include "ControlTreeView.h"

  class DragDropMainWindow : public QMainWindow
  {
      Q_OBJECT

  public:
      DragDropMainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
      ~DragDropMainWindow();

  private:
      Ui::DragDropMainWindowClass m_ui;

      ControlTreeView  *m_controlTree;
  };

  #endif // DRAGDROPMAINWINDOW_H


  // dragdropmainwindow.cpp

  #include "dragdropmainwindow.h"

  DragDropMainWindow::DragDropMainWindow(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
      : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
  {
     m_ui.setupUi(this);

     // Create a model to control the view
     m_controlTree = new ControlTreeView(NULL);
     m_ui.m_treeView->setModel(m_controlTree);
  }

  DragDropMainWindow::~DragDropMainWindow()
  {

  }


// ControlTreeView.h

  #pragma once

  #include <QAbstractItemModel>
  #include <QModelIndex>
  #include <QStringList>
  #include <QVector>
  #include <QList>

  class TreeItem
  {
  public:
     TreeItem(const QVector<QVariant> &data, TreeItem *parent = 0);
     ~TreeItem();

     TreeItem *child(int number);
     int childCount() const;
     int columnCount() const;
     QVariant data(int column) const;
     bool insertChildren(int position, int count, int columns);
     bool insertColumns(int position, int columns);
     TreeItem *parent();
     bool removeChildren(int position, int count);
     bool removeColumns(int position, int columns);
     int childNumber() const;
     bool setData(int column, const QVariant &value);

  private:
     QList<TreeItem*>     childItems;
     QVector<QVariant>    itemData;
     TreeItem             *parentItem;
  };


  class ControlTreeView : public QAbstractItemModel
  {
     Q_OBJECT

  public:

     enum TREE_COLUMNS
     {
        eCOLUMN_FILENAME
     };


     ControlTreeView(QObject *parent);
     ~ControlTreeView(void);

     QModelIndex index (int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
     QModelIndex parent (const QModelIndex & index) const;
     int rowCount (const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
     int columnCount (const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
     QVariant data (const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
     Qt::ItemFlags flags (const QModelIndex & index) const;
     bool setData (const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::EditRole);
     QVariant headerData (int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
     bool insertRows (int row, int count, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex());
     //bool insertColumns (int column, int count, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex());
     bool removeRows (int row, int count, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex());
     //bool removeColumns (int column, int count, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex());


     bool dropMimeData (const QMimeData * data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent);
     Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions() const;
     QStringList mimeTypes () const;
     QMimeData *mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const;

     bool setHeaderData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                       const QVariant &value, int role);

  private:
     TreeItem *getItem(const QModelIndex &jobIndex) const;

     TreeItem             *m_rootItem;      // Root of the view tree
  };

// ControlTreeView.cpp
  #include "ControlTreeView.h"

  #include <QtGui>
  #include <QtGui/QGraphicsView>

  class TreeColumn
  {
  public:
     ControlTreeView::TREE_COLUMNS   m_enumColumn;
     QString                                   m_header;
     int                                       m_index;
  };


  static const int NUMBER_COLUMNS = 1;
  static TreeColumn s_columns[NUMBER_COLUMNS];

  TreeItem::TreeItem(const QVector<QVariant> &data, TreeItem *parent)
  {
     parentItem = parent;
     itemData = data;
  }

  TreeItem::~TreeItem()
  {
     qDeleteAll(childItems);
  }

  TreeItem *TreeItem::parent()
  {
     return parentItem;
  }

  TreeItem *TreeItem::child(int number)
  {
     return childItems.value(number);
  }

  int TreeItem::childCount() const
  {
     return childItems.count();
  }

  int TreeItem::childNumber() const
  {
     if (parentItem)
        return parentItem->childItems.indexOf(const_cast<TreeItem*>(this));

     return 0;
  }

  int TreeItem::columnCount() const
  {
     return itemData.count();
  }

  QVariant TreeItem::data(int column) const
  {
     return itemData.value(column);
  }

  bool TreeItem::setData(int column, const QVariant &value)
  {
     if (column < 0 || column >= itemData.size())
        return false;

     itemData[column] = value;
     return true;
  }

  bool TreeItem::insertChildren(int position, int count, int columns)
  {
     if (position < 0 || position > childItems.size())
        return false;

     for (int row = 0; row < count; ++row) 
     {
        QVector<QVariant> data(columns);
        TreeItem *item = new TreeItem(data, this);
        childItems.insert(position, item);
     }

     return true;
  }

  bool TreeItem::removeChildren(int position, int count)
  {
     if (position < 0 || position + count > childItems.size())
        return false;

     for (int row = 0; row < count; ++row)
        delete childItems.takeAt(position);

     return true;
  }

  bool TreeItem::insertColumns(int position, int columns)
  {
     if (position < 0 || position > itemData.size())
        return false;

     for (int column = 0; column < columns; ++column)
        itemData.insert(position, QVariant());

     foreach (TreeItem *child, childItems)
        child->insertColumns(position, columns);

     return true;
  }



  ControlTreeView::ControlTreeView(QObject *parent) :
     QAbstractItemModel(parent)
  {
     QStringList headers;

     s_columns[ControlTreeView::eCOLUMN_FILENAME].m_header = QObject::tr("File");
     s_columns[ControlTreeView::eCOLUMN_FILENAME].m_index = 0;

     for (unsigned int index = 0; index < NUMBER_COLUMNS; index++)
        headers.append(s_columns[index].m_header);

     QVector<QVariant> rootData;
     foreach (QString header, headers)
        rootData << header;

     m_rootItem = new TreeItem(rootData);

  }

  ControlTreeView::~ControlTreeView()
  {
     delete m_rootItem;
  }

  int ControlTreeView::columnCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const 
  { 
     return NUMBER_COLUMNS; 
  };

  TreeItem *ControlTreeView::getItem(const QModelIndex &index) const
  {
     if (index.isValid()) 
     {
        TreeItem *item = static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());
        if (item) return item;
     }
     return m_rootItem;
  }

  int ControlTreeView::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
  {
     TreeItem *parentItem = getItem(parent);

     return parentItem->childCount();
  }


  Qt::ItemFlags ControlTreeView::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
  {
     //if (!index.isValid())
     //   return 0;

     //return Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled;

      Qt::ItemFlags defaultFlags = Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;

      if (index.isValid())
          return Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags;
      else
          return Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags;
  }

  QModelIndex ControlTreeView::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
  {
     if (parent.isValid() && parent.column() != 0)
        return QModelIndex();

     TreeItem *parentItem = getItem(parent);

     TreeItem *childItem = parentItem->child(row);
     if (childItem)
        return createIndex(row, column, childItem);
     else
        return QModelIndex();
  }

  QModelIndex ControlTreeView::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
  {
     if (!index.isValid())
        return QModelIndex();

     TreeItem *childItem = getItem(index);
     TreeItem *parentItem = childItem->parent();

     if (parentItem == m_rootItem)
        return QModelIndex();

     return createIndex(parentItem->childNumber(), 0, parentItem);
  }

  QVariant ControlTreeView::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const
  {
     if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

     switch (role)
     {
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
        case Qt::EditRole:
           {
              TreeItem *item = getItem(index);
              return item->data(index.column());
           }
           break;

        case Qt::DecorationRole:
           {
              if (index.column() == 0)
              {
                 if (!index.parent().isValid())   // Only decorate for 
                 {
                    //QString file = m_jobList->GetJobSrcFileName(index.row());
                    //if (!file.isEmpty())
                    //   return IconCache::Get().Load(file);
                 }
              }
           }
           break;
     }

     return QVariant();
  }


  bool ControlTreeView::setHeaderData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                       const QVariant &value, int role)
  {
     if (role != Qt::EditRole || orientation != Qt::Horizontal)
        return false;

     bool result = m_rootItem->setData(section, value);

     if (result)
        emit headerDataChanged(orientation, section, section);

     return result;
  }

  QVariant ControlTreeView::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
   {
       if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
           return m_rootItem->data(section);

       return QVariant();
   }


  QStringList ControlTreeView::mimeTypes () const
  {
     QStringList mimeTypes;

     mimeTypes += "text/uri-list";
     mimeTypes +=  "text/conversion-job-tree";

     return mimeTypes;
  }

  QMimeData *ControlTreeView::mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const
  {
     qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
     QMimeData *mimeData = 0;

     // If the window is out off focus a file is dragged from outside of the app
     // This is not normal behaviour as this function should not be call if
     // the drag comes from outside of the app (??). 
     mimeData = new QMimeData();
     QByteArray encodedData;

     QDataStream stream(&encodedData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

     foreach (QModelIndex index, indexes) {

        if (index.isValid() &&  !index.parent().isValid()) 
        {
           stream << index.row();
        }
        else
           if (index.parent().isValid())
              stream << -1;
     }

     mimeData->setData("text/conversion-job-tree", encodedData);

     return mimeData;
  }

  Qt::DropActions ControlTreeView::supportedDropActions() const
  {
     return Qt::CopyAction;
  }


  bool ControlTreeView::dropMimeData(const QMimeData * data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent)
  {
     qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;

     if (action == Qt::IgnoreAction)
        return true;

     bool success = false;

     if (action == Qt::CopyAction)
     {
        if (data->hasFormat("text/uri-list"))
        {
           QList<QUrl>     urls = data->urls();

           for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); ++i)
           {
              QString file = urls[i].toLocalFile();

              if (file != "")
              {
                 // Check if the file is already in the table

                 int insertRow = -1;

                 if (parent.isValid())
                    insertRow = parent.row();

                 if (insertRow == -1)
                    if (row == -1)
                       insertRow = m_rootItem->childCount();
                    else
                       insertRow = row;

                 insertRows(insertRow, 1, QModelIndex());

                 setData(index(insertRow, s_columns[ControlTreeView::eCOLUMN_FILENAME].m_index), file, Qt::EditRole);

                 success = true;
              }
           }
        }
        else
        {
           // Different MineData used for drop tree items
           if (data->hasFormat("text/conversion-job-tree"))
           {
              // Only drop on a job
              if (parent.isValid() && parent.parent().isValid())
                 return false;

              int insertRow = -1;

              if (parent.isValid())
                 insertRow = parent.row();

              if (insertRow == -1)
                 if (row == -1)
                    insertRow = m_rootItem->childCount();
                 else
                    insertRow = row;

              QByteArray encodedData = data->data("text/conversion-job-tree");
              QDataStream stream(&encodedData, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

              int srcRowIndex = -1;

              while (!stream.atEnd()) {
                 stream >> srcRowIndex;
              }

              // Exit if the source is not valid
              if (srcRowIndex == -1)
                 return false;

              if (srcRowIndex < insertRow)
              {
                 insertRow--;
                 if (insertRow < 0)
                    insertRow = 0;
              }            

              if (srcRowIndex == insertRow)
                 return false;

              // Remove the original raw
              removeRows(srcRowIndex,1);

              // Insert a new raw
              insertRows(insertRow, 1, QModelIndex());

              //setData(index(insertRow, s_columns[ConversionJobTreeViewCtrl::eCOLUMN_FILENAME].m_index), m_jobList->At(insertRow)->GetBaseSrcFileName(), Qt::EditRole);

              return success;
           }
        }
     }
     else
        success = false;

     return success;
  }

  bool ControlTreeView::insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent)
  {
     TreeItem *parentItem = getItem(parent);
     bool success;

     beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1);
     success = parentItem->insertChildren(position, rows, m_rootItem->columnCount());
     endInsertRows();

     return success;
  }

   bool ControlTreeView::removeRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent)
   {
       TreeItem *parentItem = getItem(parent);
       bool success = true;

       beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1);
       success = parentItem->removeChildren(position, rows);
       endRemoveRows();

       return success;
   }

  bool ControlTreeView::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
  {
     if (role != Qt::EditRole)
        return false;

     TreeItem *item = getItem(index);
     bool result = item->setData(index.column(), value);

     if (result)
        emit dataChanged(index, index);

     return result;
  }
```